# execute script at particular time in amazon ec2 linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron, gnu-screen

I am newbi in amazon ec2 as well as linux,

I am working on pentaho kettle, for starting my job process i m using following command in amazon ec2 instance,

```
cd /dev/pdi/data-integration (reaching to specific directory)

screen (the process which never die so using screen for this)

./kitchen.sh -file="/dev/pdi/pdi_transformations_jobs/capella_job.kjb" -param:ROUTE_TO_LOG="/dev/logs/capellajobOutput.log" (for starting batch file)
```

Now i want to do something like i want to start my ec2 instance as well as job process at particular given time.

i can write a cron script for this but i read some-where that amazon ec2 instance does-not support cron , am i right?

i am putting above 3 commands in 1 .sh file and trying to create a similar file like batch file so that it automatically executes all three command, but i am getting error like " no such file or directory and command not found "

so can somebody explain me what is wrong and how to achieve a particular thing what i suppose to do.

Comment: There are too many cumulative fundamental errors here for us to help you.  Perhaps for starters you should look at `nohup`, as well as the differences between the various base AMIs in EC2.

Answer (score 3):

- First, EC2 should support `cron`. If you are unsure, why don't you just test it?
- Second, to run a script it needs to have execute permissions and need to be either in your path or is called with the full file name, including location. See `man chmod`.
- Third, just calling `screen` inside a script and then expect the following command to run inside a `screen` session does not work.
- You dont want to repeatedly (e.g via cron) run a job that is supposed to never end - you'll end with very many of those and quickly your system will overload.
- I don't know Pentaho kettle, but if `/dev/` is supposed to be a directory for *development* files, don't use this name, it's reserved for *device files*, something very important for Unix/Linux and you should never use if for something else.

In the end, I am unsure what you really want to accomplish. Is this `kitchen.sh` script supposed to run permanently? In that case, you don't need (and never should) try to run it via any timed method like `cron`, but need to put it into an init script and start it together with the system, maybe with some kind of watchdog checking up on this thing.

Comment: i executed the crontab -e opened one file as i was not that familiar with cron i closed crontab then message displayed installing cron, so get confused that what went wrong.

yes i want to start my ec2 instance and kitchen.sh at some given time as well as second script which stops the same,

o 6 *** filename will execute my script for starting kitchen.sh but what script i have to writ for stating ec2 instance if it is stop.

Comment: before executing ./filename.sh i changed the permission but still getting permission error